# How to make a for loop skip a element that can't be found

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, roblox

What I want to do it find a member in the list of groups and I want selenium to click that elements profile, So I tried to make a list of how much the limit should be for what it should click but it cant find the element starting with member-100000 which is right, because their isn't any element id like that but I want it to click the correct elements on that page which I dont know how to make it possible because in that website the members change throughout time.

My Code:

```
driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/groups/650266/Trade#!/about")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('group-dropdown').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("role-3874587").click()
item = [driver.find_element_by_id("member-" + str(q)) for q in range(100000, 10000000000)]
for i in range(0, 1000):
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("avatar-container").click()
for items in item():
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Error Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="member-100000"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```

Screenshot:
[image]

And the Parts of what I want the bot to click  on[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find all avatars like:

```
avatar_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('avatar-container')
```

and then click on each of them like:

```
avatar_links[0].click()
```

or in loop:

```
    for avatar in avatar_links:
        avatar.click()
```

But be careful because clicking on avatar redirects you to another page with no member elements and you should come back to previous page before clicking another avatar.

Comment: How do I click an element in the group that I want to be using for that situation.

Comment: Could you please clarify for me which of the elements you want to click on and describe the selection criteria?

Comment: I want to click the group section of “Rich Traders”

Comment: Like I want it to loop the people who are in that section of that specific group

Comment: Also the error I get whenever I run it is ```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```